# What is the replacement of cv.Get2D in opencv 3.4?

Tags: python, opencv

As title, I'm trying to convert cv to cv2 but I don't know how to fix this issue

```
cv.Get2D(self.image,int(sv[1]),int(sv[0]))
```

I tried to use like this, but it returns that cv2 has no attribute Get2D:

```
cv2.Get2D(self.image,int(sv[1]),int(sv[0]))
```

Anyone can share me a solution?
Thanks

Comment: I do not know for Get2D but if the postion arguments are width and height then you can access to the value of the pixel as: self.image[height,width] if your image is grayscale of self.image[height,width,:] if it has channels.

Comment: Thank guy. It works well for me

Answer (score 2):

`self.image` should be an numpy.ndarray, thus you can get an element by simply indexing image: `self.image[int(sv[1]), int(sv[0])]`

Comment: A link to [array indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/basics.indexing.html) would make this answer even better ;)

Comment: Thanks. It works with self.image[int(sv[0]), int(sv[1])]